# Using Liquid tags for navigation on Jekyll site

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have the following structure on my Jekyll site:

```
- Home
- Knowledge Base (/kb/)
 - Post 1 (/kb/post1/)
 - Post 2 (/kb/post2/)
- About
```

On each page except Home I have navigation which leads to the home page. In the posts I have navigation which leads to the knowledge base. I already have some code and it works. But is there any way to make it more simple?

The code for the navigation:

```
<nav>
 {% if page.title == 'Knowledge Base' %}
   <a href="/"></a>
 {% elsif page.path contains 'kb' %}
   {% unless page.title == 'Knowledge Base' %}
     <a href="/kb/"></a>
   {% endunless %}
 {% elsif page.title != 'Home' %}
   <a href="/"></a>
 {% endif %}
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved all my posts to `kb` folder inside `_posts` and ended up using this code:

```
<nav>
  {% if page.path contains '_posts/kb' %}
    <a href="/kb/"></a>
  {% elsif page.title != "Home" %}
    <a href="/"></a>
  {% endif %}
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

> From posts you can go only to knowledge base. From knowledge base and all other pages, except home, you can go to home page. On the home page there is no navigation.

```
<nav>
 {% if page.title == 'Knowledge Base' and page.title == 'About'% %}
    <a href="/"></a>
 {% endif %}

 {% if page.title != 'Home' 
       and page.title != 'Knowledge Base' 
       and page.title != 'About' %}
       <a href="/kb/"></a>
 {% endif %}
</nav>
```

anyway, instead of `page.title` I would use a different page variable in the header (e.g. `page.template`) not strictly dependent on the specific page title (or language) that could change.

Also consider to make this code snippet as a single file to include for an easier mantainance.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it, but navigation on About page leads to knowledge base, instead of home page. Navigation on all pages should lead to home page, except navigation in posts.

Comment: except navigation in posts and the home itself? It's not possible to jump to the home if I'm reading a post?

Comment: Yes, that's right. From posts you can go only to knowledge base. From knowledge base and all other pages, except home, you can go to home page. On the home page there is no navigation.

Comment: see my update. anyway I strongly suggest to use a specific variable